# Change displayed name for embedded email in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I've embedded email messages in a Word 2010 document (copy from Outlook, paste in Word) and each message is shown as a mail icon with the email subject as the caption.

I want to change the caption displayed but I can't find out how... I tried right-click->Packager shell object object->convert->change icon, but this changes the icon type from a mail icon to a generic icon and that's no good.

How can I achieve this - to change the text label shown under the embedded icon?

Comment: Under Packager Shell Object Object don't you see a *Rename Package* option?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing of my own, it appears that this cannot be achieved in this way as the e-mail item is an object whose properties are predetermined from within Outlook before being pasted into the Word document.

You are looking to treat this object's name - although part of the object / icon itself - as a caption, which cannot be done as it has been copied from an external source and was not created in Word to begin with.  Consider - and treat - it as an individual entity whose properties cannot be modified in this way.

**However**, it is not all bad news and can be achieved via the following steps (which I myself have tested and can confirm the validity of):

- Copy e-mail item from within Outlook
- Paste into a separate location on your computer (desktop will suffice)
- Rename the object on the desktop
- Copy newly-renamed object and paste into Word document

Please note that you may lose the icon in this process, which should be easy to restore.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If a "Convert" option is offered for the object then selecting "Convert" followed by "Change Icon" will allow you to change the object's caption.
[image: Right click, convert]
[image: Change Icon]

Answer (score 0):

My displayed label/caption/text under icon is e.g. "abc".

In Excel 2013 I was able to right-click the object, then go to: "Packager Shell Object Object" -> "Rename package". And there in "Label" I changed from "abc.msg" to "ABC.msg".

It hasn't changed immediately, but after I e.g. saved the document it got successfully refreshed.